# AngularJS Dynamc templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

another angularJS question!
Im still trying to learn directives, and one thing that im looking at doing it to display a different template based on a scope item that is passed in. Ive googled and found multiple ways to achieve this used both

```
link:
```

and

```
controller:
```

and have seen reviews suggesting that this can not / should not be done using the

```
templateURL :
```

im a little confused as this is the way i have achieved it..

i have 2 templates :-

```
<div>here is my name :- {{name}}, and im template 1</div>
<div>here is my name :- {{name}}, and im template 2</div>
```

Here is the directive

```
   .directive('createDirective', function () {

      return {
          scope: {name:'&myName'},
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {

              switch (tAttrs.template)
              {
                  case '1': 
                      return 'app/event/showname.html'
                      break;
                  case '2' :
                      return 'app/event/showname2.html'
                      break;
              }
              console.log('template')
          },
       }
  });
```

and the directive in the HTML

```
<create-directive my-name="bob" template="1"></create-directive>
```

this seems to be working, and a much simpler solution.. however,  whats the reason why i shouldnt be using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect to say that you *shouldn't* be using it a `templateUrl` function - it is provided for a reason.

And for the limited example that you showed, it works fine.

But, your example does not illustrate what said you wanted, namely:

> "...display a different template based on a **scope item** that is passed in"

You are not passing a scope variable when you do `template="1"`. If you were to pass a scope variable, it would look like this:

```
<create-directive my-name="bob" template="{{templateNum}}">
```

where `templateNum` is a variable set on the scope, which could equal `"1"`. In this case, `templateURL` function approach will not work, since the `{{templateNum}}` expression will not yet be interpolated. So, `tAttrs.template` would actually equal to the string `"{{templateNum}}"`, not to the value `"1"`

Comment: thank you again,  makes sense, hence why the examples all provide the dynamic template from within the link: or controller: